# Alternatives for placeholders in Markdown?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown, code-formatting

Which one is the best way of writing a "placeholder" (I don't know if it has another name) in Markdown? I mean a string inside a code listing that the reader should consider as a generic variable, that they should replace with an actual value—a string of their will.

I've seen some notations:

- Put the placeholder inside `<this>`. Could be mistaken for an HTML tag.
- Put in `<THIS>`. Could also be mistaken for an HTML tag.
- Put in `THIS`.  Could be mistaken for some other uppercase text such as an SQL keyword.

Could it be better using some other awkward symbol from keyboards? I'm writing on a Spanish keyboard and I thought it could be better to do it like `¨this¨` since in Spanish we always use the diaeresis symbol, `¨`, over some letters (*e* or *u*; it's a symbol we seldom use). Is there some "spare" symbol in English keyboards?

In that case, what would be the best output for that Markdown code?

Comment: `in Spanish we always use the ¨ symbol (diéresis) over some letters (e or u; it's a symbol we seldom use).` **Are you saying you always, sometimes, or rarely use this symbol?** This sentence contradicts itself.

Comment: @Stormblessed, in Spanish we never use the *¨* symbol by itself. Whenever we use it, it's as an accent over some vocal, as in *pingüino*.

Comment: The diaeresis just appears to be an odd-looking double quote symbol. I wouldn’t have guessed it was a diaeresis without being told, precisely because it is a diacritic that’s normally never used without a base letter.

Comment: *[thingamajig](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thingamajig#Noun)* or *[whatchamacallit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whatchamacallit#Noun)*?

Answer (score 9):

That's a purely stylistic choice, and nothing to do with Markdown.

For myself, I prefer curly braces: `{replace-this-with-your-value}`

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add this as a comment to the [answer by ale](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301512/835281), but it was too long...

For myself, I'd prefer a markup language that enables you to markup placeholders in code (in documentation) *semantically*. For example, in DITA, a `<varname>` element nested in a `<codeblock>`. But, er, I'm not thrilled with the semantic mapping there. Is a placeholder for a literal string,
such as a component of a file path, really a "variable"? I feel the need for a specialized element here (dives down specialization rabbit hole).

On IBM mainframes, where I spend some of my time, angle brackets are the typical choice for placeholders in job control language (JCL).

Returning to Markdown, and to code in documentation, you have to escape at least the left angle bracket; and that's an ugly wrinkle, given that "a Markdown-formatted document should be publishable as-is, as plain text, without looking like it’s been marked up with tags or formatting instructions".

Depending on whether you can (and want to) fall back to HTML in your Markdown, you could use `<var>` inside `<code>`, if you're okay with italics, and/or any other properties you want to set in the CSS (if you have control over that CSS). But even then, your result depends on what's processing that Markdown. I've just tried that in a README.md in Atlassian Bitbucket Server (5.13.1), and the `<var>` gets stripped. And now, we're talking about HTML, not Markdown.

Sigh.

So, what am I saying? If you stick to Markdown, I can't think of a better choice than curly braces, as already recommended by ale.